# How to run bash script from the mounted volume in docker and exposing the port into outside the container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile contains

```
FROM java:8
```

Iam running this by mounting my host directory into docker by following command

```
docker run -it -p 8585:9090 -v ~/Docker/:/data d23bdf5b1b1b /data/bin/script.sh
```

I am able to run this successfully but the problem is when i try to access it from browser i am not able to see anything because of port conflicting 
,2 services are running on same port ..

How to solve this ?

Comment: The information you gave is insufficient. Please tell which service is running on which port, how are you running those services, do those service belong to a image or to your system

Comment: here iam using image of java:8 , iam running java microservices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to run a script in a new container and that container then exists. It has nothing to with any existing container that is running.

Also when your specify a command to be run with docker it would not run the CMD command that you had defined while building the Dockerfile.

So what you need to do is below.

```
docker run -d -p 8585:9090 -v ~/Docker/:/data d23bdf5b1b1b
```

After the above container is run it will print the ID of the new container. Now you want to execute your command in this new container

```
docker exec -it <containerid> /data/bin/script.sh
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working now but there is small change in the docker run command i.e docker run -d -it  -p 8585:9090 -v ~/Docker/:/data d23bdf5b1b1b   we have to use both -d as well as -it to start else it will be exited immediately

Comment: Then you probably need `-d -t`. `-i` should not be needed

Comment: Also i have one more doubt is it possible to execute the script using dockerfile itself i mean without using docker exec .I want to run the script which is present in the mounted volume

Comment: Yes, you can. Create a init script inside Dockerfile and run that at start. This script will check the presence of script in the volume path `/data/bin` and execute that first and then the main process

Comment: For creating images to run microservice which one is prefered to use docker volume or docker copy in dockerfile?
Microservice config file will be keep on changing so which one is prefered to use